# Approving Access Requests automatically using a SharePoint Timer Job

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development

I have a SharePoint Timer Job  which I want to approve all outstanding Access Requests.  I am using SP2013 SP1 August 2016 CU.

How do I do this in C# ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an API `SPAccessRequests.ChangeRequestStatus` which you can use to approve outstanding Access Requests.